wildfly embedded-server, write log message via CLI
I'm configuring my WF Servers via embedded server and it runs fine, but I want to know what logs are from the embedded startup and which are from the regular WF process in the server.log.
My idea was to extend the logger with an string or more lacy to write messages with echo or else.
Any idea how to do that?

As an alternativ some prefix/suffix somewhere in the log would work too

Do you have examples of the log messages you're referring to? How do you start the embedded server? With the jboss-cli.sh?
